# Group by age array returns empty

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to calculate users age, and then group those results like the following:

```
public function setAge($users)
{
    if($users)
        foreach($users as $user)
        {
            $now    = Carbon::now();
            $u->age = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $u->birth_date);
            $u->age = $now->diffInYears($u->age)
        }

    return $users;
}

public function groupByAge($users)
{
    $ageGroups = ['less than 20', 'more than 20'];
    foreach ($users as $u) 
       switch($u->age) {
           case ($u->age < 20)
               $ageGroups['less than 20'] += 1;
               break;
           case($u->age > 20)
               $ageGroups['more than 20'] += 1;
               break;
       }

    return $age;
}           

public function index()
{
    $users = DB::table('users')->get;
    $users = $this->setAge($users);
    $users = $this->groupByAge($users);

    dd($groupByAge);

    return view('/users/',['users'=> $users]);
}
```

However when I `dd($groupByAge)` I'm always receiving

> empty array like ('key' => 0)

I'm not sure if I'm not passing `$users` correctly or what is the issued.

Comment: `$groupByAge` is not the variable you want to dd. instead dd `$users` variable

Comment: What if `$u->age == 20`?

Comment: What does `endforeach` and `endif` mean in PHP context? What is `$u`? You using it `u->birth_date` (btw. missing a $ sign) without declaring it before. Please provide a code example without syntax errors.

Comment: Check your `groupByAge` function, it returns `$age` which is never set. And that `foreach` isn't closed anywhere? Also, `$ageGroup['less then 20']` is not the same as `$ageGroup['less than 20']`.

Comment: @commonsense ``endif`` and ``endforeach`` are [alternative syntaxes](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php). Didn't know it either.. **BUT** ``:`` are missing for the syntax

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * @return array()
 */
public function setAge($users) {
  if($users) {
    foreach($users as &$user) {
      $now = Carbon::now();
      $user->age = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $user->birth_date);
      $user->age = $now->diffInYears($user->age);
    }
  }
 return $users;
}

/**
 * @return array()
 */
public function groupByAge($users) {
   $ageGroups = ['less than 20', 'more than 20'];
   $ageGroup = [];
    foreach ($users as $u) { 
        switch($u->age) {
          case ($u->age < 20) :
             $ageGroup['less_then_20'] = 1;
          break;
         case($u->age >= 20) :
             $ageGroup['more_than_20'] = 1;
         break;
         default:
             $ageGroup['error'] = 'error';
         break;
     }
   }
   return $ageGroup;
 }           

  public function index() {
    $users = DB::table('users')->get;
    $users = $this->setAge($users);
    $users = $this->groupByAge($users);

    print_r("<pre>");
    print_r($users);
    print_r("</pre>");die();

    return view('/users/',['users'=> $users]);
 }
```

Comment: you see `groupByAge($users)`  this method array variable` $ageGroups ` isn't using in switch case array variable. and in this code too much error solved.

Comment: Why change ``+1`` as only ``1`` in ``$ageGroup[A_KEY] =``, the result will only be 1 even if there are more than 1 person in the age category concerned

Answer (score 1):

Carbon provides a method to calculate the age directly. So, assuming that `$birth_date` already is cast to Carbon instance, it is possible to call `age` on that.

I am not sure if you want just count the users in the certain age groups or if you want to group them. As the title indicates to group the users into age groups, you can do the following:

```
public function index() {
    $groupedUsers = User::all()->mapToGroups(function($user, $key) {
        if ($user->birth_date->age < 20) {
            $ageGroups['less than 20'][] = $user
        } else {
            $ageGroups['more than 20'][] = $user
        }

        return $ageGroups;
    });


    return view('/users/',[
    'users'=> $groupedUsers
    ]);
 }
```

Comment: I think keep using Carbon for the 2 functions is the best answer

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
public function index() {
    $users = DB::table('users')->get;
    $users = $this->setAge($users);
    $users = $this->groupByAge($users);
    dd($users); exit();
    return view('/users/',[
      'users'=> $users]);

}
```

Comment: why would I dd it and then exit()?